# How to decide column value based on next row

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using Teradata 16.20.53.13 and have a table (minimized version):

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1
     (
      std_nm VARCHAR(50),      
      std_age INTEGER
     );
```

With data (minimum subset):

```
insert into TABLE_1 values ('abc', 31);
insert into TABLE_1 values ('abc', 36);
insert into TABLE_1 values ('abc', 35);
insert into TABLE_1 values ('xyz', 17);
insert into TABLE_1 values ('xyz', 14);
```

[image: TABLE_1]

What I want is to have count, sum and average of `std_age` only for last unique value of `std_nm`.
One approach I followed gives me desired result but with count, sum and average in all rows:

```
    select t1.std_nm, 
           t1.std_age, 
           t2.name_count, 
           t2.sum_age, 
           t2.avg_age
      from TABLE_1 as t1
inner join (
              select std_nm, 
                     count(std_nm) as name_count, 
                     sum(std_age) as sum_age, 
                     avg(std_age) as avg_age
                from TABLE_1
            group by std_nm
           ) t2
        on t1.std_nm = t2.std_nm
  order by t1.std_nm;
```

With above SQL my result looks like:

[image: Result_1]

**Question:** How can I get result with zero/null/blank in `name_count`, `sum_age` and `avg_age` for all unique values of `std_nm` except the last one. So result I am looking for is:

[image]

I am trying to use CASE while selecting `name_count`, `sum_age` and `avg_age` but I think there might be a better/cleaner way to do this. Maybe by using join in smarter way or something else. I am open to all options that work on Teradata 16.

Comment: I guess the first question you should ask yourself is: what is the last value? Is it 'abc', 35 or 'abc', 31 or something other

Comment: It won't matter but if that's needed then let's say largest value for 'abc' (36) and largest value for 'xyz' (17). But It would be perfectly fine if it's smallest or any other value of `std_age`. I just want that the last value of `std_nm` in final result should have "count", "sum" and "avg". Rest should be zero/blank/null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT D.std_nm,D.std_age,D.XCOL,
 CASE 
   WHEN D.XCOL=1 THEN SUB_Q.avg_age
   ELSE NULL
 END AS AVG_AGE,
CASE
 WHEN D.XCOL=1 THEN SUB_Q.name_count 
 ELSE NULL
END AS NAME_COUNT,
CASE
 WHEN D.XCOL=1 THEN SUB_Q.sum_age
 ELSE NULL
END AS SUM_AGE
FROM 
(
   SELECT T.std_nm,T.std_age,
   ROW_NUMBER()OVER (PARTITION BY T.std_nm ORDER BY T.std_age DESC)XCOL 
   FROM TABLE_1 AS T
)D
JOIN
(
   select std_nm, 
                 count(std_nm) as name_count, 
                 sum(std_age) as sum_age, 
                 avg(std_age) as avg_age
            from TABLE_1
        group by std_nm
)SUB_Q ON D.std_nm=SUB_Q.std_nm
```

Could you please try the above if it is suitable for you

Comment: It work great and exactly what I was looking for. I just added `ORDER BY D.std_nm,D.std_age;` at the end and changed column sequence to `NAME_COUNT`, `SUM_AGE` and `AVG_AGE`.
Thank you @Sergey. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

@Sergey's answer can be simplified by using Group Aggregates to avoid the join. This is a lot of cut&paste, but should result in a single step in Explain:

```
SELECT std_nm,std_age
  ,CASE
     WHEN Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY std_nm ORDER BY std_age DESC)=1
     THEN Count(std_nm) Over (PARTITION BY std_nm )   
   END AS NAME_COUNT
  ,CASE
     WHEN Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY std_nm ORDER BY std_age DESC)=1 
     THEN Sum(std_age) Over (PARTITION BY std_nm )
   END AS SUM_AGE
  ,CASE 
     WHEN Row_Number() Over (PARTITION BY std_nm ORDER BY std_age DESC)=1 
     THEN Avg(std_age) Over (PARTITION BY std_nm )
   END AS AVG_AGE
FROM TABLE_1 
;
```